# How to extract a number from brackets (an ending part of a string)?

Tags: c#, numbers, extract, brackets

My question concerns extracting an integer number from a string (in C#). There is a string which can have an integer positive number in round brackets in the end (without leading zeros), e.g. "This is a string (125)". I would like to write a code validating whether it has such a form, and if so, extracting the number and the rest from it. For example, if the string were "This is a string (125)", the results should be "This is a string" (type: string), and 125 (integer). If the string were "Another example (7)", the results should be "Another example", and 7. Would regex be useful, or should I rather write a parsing function?

Comment: Regex is your best bet. Much easier as well

Comment: You can also try string.Split()

Comment: Can the string part (before the number part) include brackets, like "A (third) example (49)"?

Comment: If you don't want to use regex, a simple string.LastIndexOf() to find the brackets works as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
string firstPart = Regex.Match(inputString, @"\(([^)]*)\)").Groups[0].Value;
int number;
Int32.TryParse(Regex.Match(inputString, @"\(([^)]*)\)").Groups[1].Value, out number);
```

EDIT:

Obviously you can optimise this and not do the Match twice but this shows how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If the input value always has same structure (like /type/bracket/value/bracket) then you can do it via:
1) RegEx
2) String.Split()
3) String.IndexOf()

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression `\((\d})\)$` that will much the number to the end of the string as a group.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string testString = "This is a string (125)asbcd";
        string[] stringPart = testString.Split('(', ')');
```

Here stringPart[0] is the string part, and stringPart[1] is the numeric part.